# Finding the number of unique values that contain another set of unique values

Tags: bash, shell

For example my text file looks something like this:

```
year, user, tweet
2009, Katie, I love playing football
2010, James, I play football
2013, Bob, I play basketball
2013, James, I play Baseball
```

The delimiter is ',' and I want to count how many unique users have mentioned the exact word 'play' in their tweet using BASH in a one liner.

The output of this should be 2, as James mentions 'play' twice and Bob once (No Katie as her word is 'playing'), so 2 people.

I have tried this:

```
$ cut -d ',' -f 2,3 Dataset.txt | grep "\<play\>" | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: `awk -F, '/play[[:blank:]]/{a[$2]++} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' Dataset.txt` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your pipeline is while `uniq -c` will provide a count of the unique occurrences, but `"James, I play Baseball"` and `"James, I play football"` will be considered unique. You can limit the check to the first `N` characters with the `-w N` option to `uniq` (in your case `-w3`), but you are much better off (and much, much more efficient) using a single call to `awk`.

Here you are concerned with the 2nd field (the name) and whether `play` occurs in the record. You can use `/play[[:blank:]]/` (or `/[[:blank:]]play[[:blank:]]/`) as the test for `"play"` alone). Then each time a record containing `"play"` alone is encountered, you save the number in the array `a[]` indexed by the name (e.g. `a[$2]`). You just increment the number in the index for each name and then using the `END` rule, you output the name and the number of occurrences.

That makes the task quite simple, e.g.

```
awk -F, '/[[:blank:]]play[[:blank:]]/{a[$2]++} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' Dataset.txt
```

**Output**

```
 James 2
 Bob 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have only recently started learning bash, this was incredibly helpful.
May I also ask the purpose of [[:blank:]]?

Comment: You will do fine. Learning is a slow process. If you are doing any type text processing, learning `awk` is well worth the effort. It is the Swiss Army-Knife of text processing. See [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents). Good luck with your scripting!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
grep -wF play Dataset.txt | cut -f 2 -d , |sort -u | wc -l
```

?